# Woocommerce вариации не меняют изображение в теме Nitro

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Я добавил нужный атрибут и в админ панеле, добавил фото к каждой вариации. Но в данной теме Nitro не меняется основное изображение при выборе другого атрибута (в корзине отображается нужное), в отличии от стандартных тем twenty.. - там все работает как нужно. Помогите пожалуйста, мучаюсь 3 день уже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: WooCommerce последней версии, а тема не обновлена, скорее всего. Что WooCommerce пишет в Статусе Системы? Не ругается на устаревшие файлы темы?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего устарел WooCommerce шаблон внутри темы, решение есть в официальной документации https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/fix-outdated-templates-woocommerce/